# JQuery reapply zebra-striping after GET request

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table with a "zebra-stripe" CSS3 class:

```css
.zebra-stripe tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #c6e1ff;
}

.zebra-stripe tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

Above the table is an entry field, whereupon a user submit will prepend a row with JQuery and POST.

This happens with:

```js
function submit(id) {
  $.post(
    "URL",  // uses template toolkit 'c.uri_for' to actually add message in database 
    { 
      msgtype: 'some-type',
      msg: $('#some-id').val()
    }, 
    function (data) { 
      $('#table-id').prepend(data);
    }
  );
  $('#some-id').val('');
  return false;
}
```

This code prepends a row at the top of my table, and all the CSS is fine and dandy. However, upon removing any given row (each row has a "remove" button), using the following JQUERY with a GET:

```js
function remove(id1,rowid) {

  // uses template toolkit 'c.uri_for' to actually remove message in database
  $.get('URL', function (data) { 
    $('#' + rowid).hide();
  });

  //attempt to reapply styles
  $('#field-note-table').removeClass("zebra-stripe");
  $('#field-note-table').addClass("zebra-stripe");

  return false;
}
```

does not reapply the CSS (breaks the zebra-striping). How do I get it to re-apply the CSS after having removed the row?

Comment: Where you use `remove` metohod?

Comment: @j08691 sorry, didn't clarify. I'm using template toolkit, so my "URL" is replaced with a `c.uri_for` call to actually add or remove the message in the database. So it's being hidden, but it is also being removed in the background.

Comment: @Shaddow Not sure I understand. Each row has a remove button, which calls the `remove` function when clicked.

Comment: @j08691 Ah... hide() != remove()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just calling `hide` makes your row so it's not displayed.  Assuming your zebra striping CSS applies different colors to each row based on odd/even, even hidden rows will be included in this striping.

If you don't need the row after you hide it, use `remove` instead; then the row won't be included in the striping any longer:

```
$.get('URL', function (data) { 
    $('#' + rowid).remove();
});
```

Otherwise, you may have to use JS to selectively stripe.

Comment: Not sure how I missed this. Guess it's the result of being a newbie at JQuery :-)

Comment: Also worth mentioning is this. If you want that nice hide/fadeOut-animation from jQuery but still fully remove the element: $('#' + rowid).fadeOut(500, function(){ $(this).remove(); });

Answer (score 1):

Put this code:

```
//attempt to reapply styles
$('#field-note-table').removeClass("zebra-stripe");
$('#field-note-table').addClass("zebra-stripe");
```

inside success method:

```
$.get('URL', function (data) { 
    $('#' + rowid).remove();
    //<--------- Here
  });
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The hidden row still exists in the DOM, and will maintain it's position in the table, breaking the zebra-stripes.

Comment: So try remove it instead of hidding if you don't need these rows in future. Look on edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove(id1,rowid) {

    // uses template toolkit 'c.uri_for' to actually add message in database
    $.get('URL', function (data) { 
        $('#' + rowid).hide(0, reStripZebra);
    });

    return false;
}

function reStripZebra() {
    $('#table-id td').each(function(index) {
        if(index % 2 == 0) $(this).removeClass("zebra-stripe");
        else $(this).addClass("zebra-stripe");
    });
}
```

Comment: Apologies for not clarifying my use of CSS3 :odd and :even selectors. The problem here is the hidden row still exists, and will be included in your .each iterations, breaking the zebra-striping.